Qualcomm WCN6855 doesn't support monitor mode, harware or software limit?
I am using the Qualcomm WCN6855 Wi-Fi chip, and it does not support monitor mode. Is this due to hardware limitations or software limitations?
If it is a software limitation, where can I request this feature?

What is the monitor mode?

sudo ip link set wlp1s0 down sudo iw wlp1s0 set monitor none sudo ip link set wlp1s0 up
What is Monitor Mode?
It is a mode in which the packets that every system sends to the WiFi are received by the system which is having the Monitor mode of WiFi instead of the WiFi itself. It means that all data is passed through the device which has the monitor mode of the WiFi.

Does this support monitor mode in Windows?

If you don't know whether this is a software or a hardware issue, then this question may be more suited in the qualcomm forums.
